# I want to pass map value to a function to run, instead getting 'too many positional argument: 0 expected, but 1 found'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this 'too many positional argument: 0 expected, but 1 found' when I am trying to access score values from the map.

**quiz.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import 'answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final VoidCallback answerQuestion;

  Quiz(
      {required this.answerQuestion,
      required this.questionIndex,
      required this.questions});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Center(
            child: Question(
              questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) => Answer(() {
                  return answerQuestion(answer['text']);
                }, answer['text'] as String))
            .toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> ```
>    ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
>        .map((answer) => Answer(() {
>              return answerQuestion(answer['text']);
>            }, answer['text'] as String))
>        .toList()
> ```

Here *Answer()* expect a function and a text value, and I am able to pass those values, but *answerQuestion()* expect a int value, which I want to pass through a Map, but I am getting this error

> > Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
> > Try removing the extra arguments.dart(extra_positional_arguments)

**home.dart**

```dart
    import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/quiz.dart';
import 'package:flutter_complete_guide/result.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  //const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // @override
  // _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var _totalScore = 0;

  _answerQuestion(int score) {
    _totalScore += score;

    setState(() {
      _questionIndex += 1;
    });
    print('Selected');
    print(_totalScore);
  }

  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Red', 'score': 8},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 6},
        {'text': 'White', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Blue', 'score': 7},
        {'text': 'Black', 'score': 9},
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite pet?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Rabbit', 'score': 4},
        {'text': 'Dog', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Cat', 'score': 8},
        {'text': 'Parrot', 'score': 6}
      ]
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your fovorite sport?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Cricket', 'score': 7},
        {'text': 'Football', 'score': 9},
        {'text': 'Hockey', 'score': 8},
        {'text': 'Badminton', 'score': 6},
      ]
    },
  ];

  // final names = ['Max', 'Manu', 'Julie'];
  // final result = (names).map((name) => Text(name)).toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 20,
          title: Text(
            'My First App',
            //style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Palette'),
            //style: GoogleFonts.getFont('Palette'),
            style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 24),
          ),
          toolbarHeight: 50,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[500],
        ),
        body: Container(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: _questionIndex < _questions.length
                ? Quiz(
                    answerQuestion: _answerQuestion(_totalScore),
                    questionIndex: _questionIndex,
                    questions: _questions,
                  )
                : Result()),
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 20,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 20, color: Colors.black),
            Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 20, color: Colors.black),
          ],
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          onTap: (index) {
            debugPrint('this is $index index');
            //Handle button tap
          },
          height: 55,
          index: 1,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOutBack,
          buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.red[500],
        ),
        // body: Text(
        //   'This is the body for my first app.',
        //   style: GoogleFonts.lato(),
        // ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `answerQuestion` method? You do have an `_answerQuestion` method on your `MyHomePage` class, but you can't call that one from your `Quiz` class.

Comment: `Quiz.answerQuestion` is declared to be a [`VoidCallback`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html), which is a function that takes zero arguments and returns nothing.  If you want the callback to take an `int` argument, then it should be declared as `final void Function(int)`.  Furthermore, when you construct the `Quiz` object, you *invoke* `_answerQuestion(_totalScore)`, but presumably you intend to pass `_answerQuestion`  itself for use as a callback.

Comment: @TmKVU, you can see on home.dart, I am passing *_answerQuestion()* to quiz.dart, and used as *answerQuestion()* in that file

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin, It worked, problem was `final VoidCallback answerQuestion` , which I replaced with `final Function answerQuestion;` and the `_answerQuestion()` return type should be void. Again Thanks a lot, you saved my day :)